# Reshape error while defining new Lambda layer in Keras

Tags: python, keras

I was trying to implement a multiplication layer in Keras and I was receiving multiple `Reshape` related errors. While they are all resolved now, I still have doubts on why this works. So here is the chunk of code that I implemented:

```
out2 = Dense(540, kernel_initializer='glorot_normal', activation='linear')(out2)
out2 = LeakyReLU(alpha=.2)(out2)
out2 = Reshape((9, 4, 15))(out2)
out2 = Lambda(lambda x: K.dot(K.permute_dimensions(x, (0, 2, 1, 3)), K.permute_dimensions(x, (0, 2, 3, 1))), output_shape=(4,9,9))(out2)
out2 = Dense(324, kernel_initializer='glorot_normal', activation='linear')(out2)
# K.dot should be of size (-1, 4, 9, 9), so I set output 324, and later on, reshape the ata
out2 = LeakyReLU(alpha=.2)(out2)
out2 = Reshape((-1, 4, 9, 9))(out2)
out2 = Permute((0, 2, 3, 1))(out2)
```

This works fine now. But I have done 3 things that I'm not comfortable with:

1. I used to have `out2 = Reshape((-1, 9, 4, 15))(out2)` instead of     `out2 = Reshape((9, 4, 15))(out2)` and I had the error

   `ValueError: Dimension must be 5 but is 4 for 'lambda_1/transpose' (op: 'Transpose') with input shapes: [?,?,9,4,15], [4].`

Apparently, I was not taking the batch size dimension into account.

2. Now I tried to correct the line `out2 = Reshape((-1, 4, 9, 9))(out2)` to `out2 = Reshape((4, 9, 9))(out2)` using the same concept, but then, it throws the error

   `ValueError: total size of new array must be unchanged`

I don't understand the inconsistency.

3. Lastly, I was wondering if removing  `output_shape=(4,9,9)` would do anything wrong to the code.

Comment: What's the value of `out2.output_shape` before the reshaping line?

Comment: The second reshaping line? To my surprise, `(None, 4, 9, 324)` I was expecting 324 as I thought I set so in Dense layer. And before the first reshape line `(None, 512) `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the problems with the batch size, Keras automatically handles it. It is just a convetion that layers represent a function to be applied to a batch, and it's the task of Keras to apply such function to every batch the model is fed with. So, basically, you should ignore the batch size when defining layers.

Also, the `Dense` layer does not work as you expect. It is applied over the last dimension of it's input. In case you want to deal with your data from that point on as a regular MLP you can use `Flatten()` before `Dense` as you would with a CNN that ends with regular fully connected layers (of course you can reshape it afterwards).

To sum up you could do something like:

```py
out2 = Dense(540, kernel_initializer='glorot_normal', activation='linear')(out2)
out2 = LeakyReLU(alpha=.2)(out2)
out2 = Reshape((9, 4, 15))(out2)
out2 = Lambda(lambda x: K.dot(K.permute_dimensions(x, (0, 2, 1, 3)), K.permute_dimensions(x, (0, 2, 3, 1))), output_shape=(4,9,9))(out2)
out2 = Flatten()(out2)
out2 = Dense(324, kernel_initializer='glorot_normal', activation='linear')(out2)
out2 = LeakyReLU(alpha=.2)(out2)
out2 = Reshape((4, 9, 9))(out2)
```

Comment: Agreed on batch size comment. Regarding `Dense` layer, thanks for making that clear. I'm rewriting a Tensorflow code and the line in Tensorflow is     `leaky_relu(tf.matmul(tf.transpose(out2, perm=[0, 2, 1, 3]), tf.transpose(out2, perm=[0, 2, 3, 1])))`, which does not explicitly flatten it. Is that implicitly being flattened and if I do flatten as you suggest, would I have the same functionality?

Comment: I don't quite understand your change, but before the `Flatten` layer, `out2` currently have values spread accross 3 dimensions (plus batch size) as the output shape suggest, so I wouldn't say that it's flattened in any way. If you want to apply `Dense` layers *regularly* you should flatten your tensor first

Comment: Your answer was precise and crystal clear. I just added an edit to the question explaining my comment for you. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to help! Answering your code update: no, the pieces of code are simply different. Anyway, if you want to ask another question, please do so with another post

Comment: That is a good idea, will do (and tag you if you had any comments for that)